# How to ignore iOS Accessibility setting for Invert Colors in versions earlier than iOS 11.0?

Tags: ios, accessibility, ios10, uiaccessibility, accessibility-api

In the Accessibility settings on iOS there is the ability to Invert Colors. However, inverting colors on images and videos isn't always desirable.

iOS 11 introduces a property called `accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors` that can be set on `UIView`s to ignore the system directive to invert its colors (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2865843-accessibilityignoresinvertcolors).

Is it possible to ignore Invert Colors on apps using earlier iOS versions than iOS 11.0?

Comment: Suggestion: Check if the user has invert colours on and if they do make the color already inverted so iOS will just invert it back to the original color which is what you want.